# Javascript - want to press button repeatedly and have same function trigger

Tags: javascript

I'm making a quiz in Javascript and I want to be able to use the same button over and over for answers without reloading the page. Here's my code:

```
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let answers = document.getElementById('answers').value;
      let inputAns = [0, 1, 2];
      for (var i = 0; i < inputAns.length; i++) {
        if (answers == inputAns[i]) {
          document.getElementById("correctAnswers").innerHTML = "&#9989;";
          inputAns++;
      } else { 
          document.getElementById("incorrectAnswers").innerHTML = "&#10060;";
         inputAns++;
      }
      }
      });
```

and

```
<button type="submit" id="nextBtn" class="nextBtn">NEXT!</button>
 </div>

<div class="correctAnswers" id="correctAnswers"></div>
<div class="incorrectAnswers" id="incorrectAnswers"></div>
```

So when the button (nextBtn) is pressed, it reads the input bar (answers) and checks to see if that matches the input of the array (inputAns). If it matches, a green check is displayed. If it doesn't, a red x is displayed. Then the loop adds to the array to make the answer change for the next question. This works one time. But when the button is pressed again, nothing happens. How can I make the function repeat so that more questions can be checked and checks or x's can appear? Thanks!

ETA: More HTML

Comment: Please put enough HTML in the question so that this code can be executed.  When posting a question asking for debugging help, it needs to be an [mcve]

Comment: Just added it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is turn your `.innerHTML` to append rather than replace (with `+=`).

You'll also want to make use of a **true equals** in the conditional, or else an empty answer will be treated as the same thing as `0`, and thus be valid for the first answer. If you do this, you'll also want to make use of `parseInt(answers)` rather than just `answers`.

After this, you'll want to shift your input array outside of your function, and set up a **current answer** variable as well. This should reference the first index of the array.

From here, you'll want to completely remove your loop, and simply run `inputAns.shift()` inside of your 'success' criteria; this will remove the first element in the array. Because of this, you're able to run the comparison against `currentAnswer = inputAns[0]`. If the first element is removed, the answer will be compared against the second element, and so on until all answers have been given.

Finally, you'll probably want to add a message or 'stop' condition when all answers have been entered. This can be done by checking `if (!inputAns.length)`.

This can be seen in the following, where the correct answers are `0`, `1`, 12` in order:

```js
let inputAns = [0, 1, 2];
let currentAnswer = inputAns[0];

document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let answers = document.getElementById('answers').value;
  if (parseInt(answers) === currentAnswer) {
    document.getElementById("correctAnswers").innerHTML += "&#9989;";
    inputAns.shift();
    if (!inputAns.length) {
      console.log("All answers provided!");
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incorrectAnswers").innerHTML += "&#10060;";
  }
  currentAnswer = inputAns[0];
});
```

```html
<input id="answers" />

<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<div id="correctAnswers"></div>
<div id="incorrectAnswers"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I need it to. Thank you for the thorough explanation!